# How do I sort albums alphabetically in Photos.app?

Tags: macos, photos.app, sort

I would like to know if I can alphabetically sort albums in Photos.app. The iPhoto method for doing this did not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re talking about sorting your list of albums alphabetically, go to **View** → **Show Sidebar** or press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>. Then right-click **Albums** in your sidebar and choose **Sort** → **By Name**.

[image: Sort Albums By Name]

If you’re asking about sorting the photos inside an album alphabetically, right-click that album in your sidebar and  choose **Sort** → **Keep Sorted By Title**. Note that most photos won’t have a title, and **Photos** will next sort by date taken.

[image: Keep Sorted By Title]

Answer (score 0):

Under the View menu, select Keep Sorted By Title to sort albums alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View > next select Albums > next click on any album to highlight it > next go back to view & select sort by title

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to View-->Albums.
2. In the My Albums listing, highlight one album and then press Command-A to select all of the albums.
3. Go back up to View and click Sort-->By Name.

All the highlighted albums will go into alphabetical order.

Answer (score -1):

I had all kind of problems with album sorting across various devices. Please take a look

https://www.thedebuguy.com/blog/photoalbumsort